# comparing two csv files in Python moving data from on to the other

Tags: python, csv, twitter, compare

I'm trying to compare 2 csv files:

**tweet6.csv** which contains all my tweet data

**tweetcheck.csv** which is will be filled by data from tweet6.csv to double check this data to see if a tweet has already been tweeted. It is empty when the script runs for the first time

Basically, i'm running a script that does a search and returns tweets that are going to be retweeted
Given that the search api will almost always returns tweets that I have already retweeted and I dont want to adjust the script manually everytime I run it, I need the csv files above to check for this and only retweet tweets that are not yet in the tweetcheck.csv

this is my highly flawed attempt at it:

```
  import tweepy, time

class TwitterAPI:
    def __init__(self):
        consumer_key = "aaaa"
        consumer_secret = "bbbb"
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        access_token = "cccc"
        access_token_secret = "ddddd"
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        self.api = tweepy.API(auth)

def tweet(self, message):
    self.api.update_status(status=message)
import csv
tweet_file_read = open('tweet6.csv')
csvreader = csv.DictReader(tweet_file_read)
tweet_file_check = open('tweetcheck.csv')
csvwriter= csv.DictWriter(tweet_file_check)
fieldnames = ['id', 'text', 'user']


if __name__ == "__main__":
    twitter = TwitterAPI()
    for tweet_file_read['id'] in csvreader:
        if tweet_file_read['id'] not in tweet_file_check['id']:
            twitter.api.retweet(tweet_file_read['id'])
            csv.writerow(tweet_file_read['id'])
            time.sleep(600)
```

I get an invalid syntax for:

```
csvwriter.writerow(tweet_file_read['id'])
```

Probably because of a systemic flaw in how i'm aproaching the problem

Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code from what I see right now-

**1.** `csv.writerow(tweet_file_read['id'])` should be

`csvwriter.writerow(tweet_file_read['id'])`

**2.** `tweet_file_check = open('tweetcheck.csv')` should be

`tweet_file_check = open('tweetcheck.csv', 'ab')`

(Since you are trying to append a row to the file, using the default mode for `open` opens the file in read-only mode)

Comment: Thanks, I did the adjustments but it still gives me the same error :S

Comment: @AmiYa Please update the question with the current code and the screenshot of the error that you are getting.